# MongoDB Lookup in array

Tags: mongodb

Good Morning.
I'm trying to query mongoDB by joining two collections. But I'm not able to do that when the primary identifier is inside an array in the secondary collection.
See my code and my collection

**Pipe Colletion**

```
{ _id: 1, deal_id: 25698}
{ _id: 2, deal_id: 45879}
{ _id: 3, deal_id: 54142}
```

**Leads Colletion**

```
{ _id: 1, name:"Teste A", deals_id:[25698,45879]}
{ _id: 2, name:"Teste B", deals_id:[54142]}
```

Desired result when searching for deal_id from the Pipe collection:

**Results**

```
{ _id: 1, deal_id: 25698, name:"Teste A"}
{ _id: 2, deal_id: 45879, name:"Teste A"}
{ _id: 3, deal_id: 54142, name:"Teste B"}
```

**My Code:**

```
db.pipedrive.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "leads",
            'let': {
                deal_id: '$deal_id'
            },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $and: [
                                {$eq: ["$$deal_id", "$deals_id"]}
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "Results"
        }
    }
]);
```

As I am currently doing, the analytics line is always returning me empty.

Can you help me?

Comment: Using your approach, you can replace `$eq` with `$in` should suffice, also `$and` is not necessary. *But* you can actually use regular `$lookup` without pipeline, on those two fields. If the foreign field is an array mongodb will compare with the array elements

Comment: hello @thammada.ts I exchanged $eq for $in. But the following error message appears: [Error] $in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing

Comment: That means `$deals_id` does not exists on some documents?

Comment: Yes there is. It is inside the Leads collection as an array @thammada.ts

Comment: The error is caused by the missing field `deals_id`, Make sure you spell it correctly, e.g. `deals_id` vs `deal_ids`, otherwise there might really be at least a document that does not have that field

Comment: Check this [playground with existing fields](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5ODYAXYP4sn) vs [playground with missing field](https://mongoplayground.net/p/E8QoKq-oWD2)

Comment: Very good. I found a solution. What you said got me thinking, so I put a check to find only documents that exist deals_id. So just put it here: "deals_id": {$exists: true} Thanks

Comment: Check an alternative solution in my answer, you should be able to do it using a simple `$lookup`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your original approach, exchanging `$eq` with `$in` should work, and since you only have one condition `$and` is not necessary. Note that `$deals_id` should exists in foreign document and must be an array, as `$in` requires the second parameter to be an array. So in case it doesn't exist we will have to wrap it with `$ifNull`

```
db.pipedrive.aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
    from: "leads",
    let: {
      deal_id: '$deal_id'
    },
    pipeline: [
      {
        $match: {
          $expr:  { $eq: ["$$deal_id", { $ifNull: ["$deals_id", []] ] }
        }
      }
    ],
    as: "Results"
  }
}
// optional other stages to output as desired shape
]);
```

**A Better alternative** would be just to use regular `$lookup`, since mongodb is able to compare the with the elements of the foreign field array. Just like with find query. This will also account for missing fields or non array fields.

```
db.pipedrive.aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
    from: "leads",
    localField: "deal_id",
    foreignField: "deals_id",
    as: "Results"
  }
}
// optional other stages to output as desired shape
  {
    $unwind: "$Results"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      deal_id: true,
      name: "$Results.name"
    }
  }
]);
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-M9ZzZa9SFi)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to get desired results. `$lookup` will take care of array as well.

```
db.pipe.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "leads",
      localField: "deal_id",
      foreignField: "deals_id",
      as: "results"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$results"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      deal_id: 1,
      name: "$results.name"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the link to check results,
https://mongoplayground.net/p/mhF6zHD9d26